# How is the E coefficients calculated or generated for the Radau IIA 5th Order?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential, runge-kutta-methods

With regard to [Scipy](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.10.1/scipy/integrate/_ivp/radau.py), the E coefficients are written out. I've seen this from different sources as well. However, I cannot find any reference to how the E coefficients were computed.

Comment: What is $E$? I distantly associate the coefficients for additional right-side evaluations to construct the dense-output interpolation (which is unavoidable for explicit methods). Then that would not be necessary for Radau, as that is a collocation method that is based on the interpolation polynomial. Thus solving the implicit step system already produces the interpolation polynomial.

Comment: @LutzLehmann The interpolator coefficients are already written down as P; please see Scipy code already referenced above. The T, C, E and P matrices are all used by the Radau function.